# Would you say "is" or "are" in this sentence?

Tags: grammar, verb-agreement

Would you say "is" or "are" in this sentence?

"His talent, combined with his personality, is/are attractive."

Comment: "combined with his personality" is a parenthetical that does not influence the grammar of the main sentence "His talent is attractive." HTH.

Answer (score 4):

You should use "is", because the subject is "His talent".